# What is an efficient way to concatenate lists?

Tags: list, scala, concatenation

When we have two lists `a` and `b`, how can one concatenate those two (order is not relevant) to a new list in an efficient way ?

I could not figure out from the Scala API, if `a ::: b` and `a ++ b` are efficient. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: It might be `reverse_:::` (for immutable.List) as this just needs to cons left-to-right .. in any case [take a peek at the source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala)

Comment: The concatenation methods of scala are pretty efficient. Concatenation does not create a completly new List. Instead it takes the two lists and references the last element of the first list to the first element of the second one.

Answer (score 9):

In Scala 2.9, the code for `:::` (prepend to list) is as follows:

```
def :::[B >: A](prefix: List[B]): List[B] =
  if (isEmpty) prefix
  else (new ListBuffer[B] ++= prefix).prependToList(this)
```

whereas `++` is more generic, since it takes a `CanBuildFrom` parameter, i.e. it can return a collection type different from `List`:

```
override def ++[B >: A, That](that: GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That = {
  val b = bf(this)
  if (b.isInstanceOf[ListBuffer[_]]) (this ::: that.seq.toList).asInstanceOf[That]
  else super.++(that)
}
```

So if your return type is `List`, the two perform identical.

The `ListBuffer` is a clever mechanism in that it can be used as a mutating builder, but eventually "consumed" by the `toList` method. So what `(new ListBuffer[B] ++= prefix).prependToList(this)` does, is first sequentially add all the elements in `prefix` (in the example `a`), taking O(|a|) time. It then calls `prependToList`, which is a *constant time* operation (the receiver, or `b`, does not need to be taken apart). Therefore, the overall time is O(|a|).

On the otherhand, as pst pointed out, we have `reverse_:::`:

```
def reverse_:::[B >: A](prefix: List[B]): List[B] = {
  var these: List[B] = this
  var pres = prefix
  while (!pres.isEmpty) {
    these = pres.head :: these
    pres = pres.tail
  }
  these
}
```

So with `a reverse_::: b`, this again takes O(|a|), hence is no more or less efficient that the other two methods (although for small list sizes, you save the overhead of having an intermediate `ListBuffer` creation).

---

In other words, if you have *knowledge* about the relative sizes of `a` and `b`, you should make sure that the prefix is the *smaller* of the two lists. If you do not have that knowledge, there is nothing you can do, because the `size` operation on a `List` takes O(N) :)

---

On the other hand, in a future Scala version you may see an improved `Vector` concatenation algorithm, as demonstrated in [this ScalaDays talk](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/scala/fast-concatenation-immutable-vectors). It promises to solve the task in O(log N) time.

Comment: Since order "does not matter", what about `reverse_:::`? I would imagine this would be `O(l)` where `l` is the number of elements in list on the left.

Comment: All versions look O(a) to me, assuming they're both lists. Left part will be copied due to immutability, right part will be shared thanks to immutability.

Comment: @Kaito - I was checking up on this, looking into `prependToList`. I think you are right, there. Will correct the answer.